# Invalid syntax for format

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic

Python 3.4 gives error to this statement. This is o print the cartesian product for fuzzy logic operations.

```
 print(f'The size of the relation will be: {len(self)}x{len(other)}')
```

I'm trying to perform the union, intersection and difference operations on fuzzy set.

Comment: python 3.4 does not support [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)... need 3.6 at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python 3.4 does not support f-strings
You could at emulate them if needed :

```
def f(s):
    return s.format(**globals())

answer = 'CRICKET'
print(f('FOOTBALL OVER {ans}'))
```

Edit:
Its better to use .format as this wouldn't work directly for len(something)

Comment: I see. It's best to use .format() as using **globals() is not optimum

Answer (score 1):

As @hiroprotagonist mentioned in the comments, f-strings were added in Python 3.6. For Python 3.x prior to Python 3.6, do this instead:

```
print('The size of the relation will be: {0}x{1}'.format(len(self), len(other)))
```

Or using old-style Python 2 formatting (don't use this if possible):

```
print('The size of the relation will be: %dx%d' % (len(self), len(other)))
```